# Does this incompatible pointer raise any problems?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the following switch case statement, in which function pointers are "returned":

```c
void getExampleById(int l, int *a, int *b, double (**f) (double), double (**F) (double, double)) {
    
    switch(l) {
        case 1:
            *a = 0; *b = 5; *f = f1; *F = F1; break;
        case 2:
            *a = 0; *b = 10; *f = f2; *F = F2; break;
        default:
            printf("something went wrong\n");
    }
}
```

Now, f1 and F1 are functions that follow the "pointer template"  `double (**f) (double), double (**F) (double, double)`. But f2 and F2 are function like

```c
double f2(double t) {

    return t;
}

double F2(double t) {

    return t;
}
```

Does this raise any serious problems when calling the function pointer returned by `getExampleById` like `(*F)(2,2)`. Might the second argument just be passed into nothing and everything is fine?

Comment: Yes, the compiler raises a warning. But I am curious what actually happens here

Comment: The problem occurs if you call it without a cast back to the proper type before the call.

Comment: Mind providing some code? Where would you cast it back? Inside switch-case?

Comment: No, before you use the function pointer to call the function

Comment: There's serious problems if you forcibly cast function pointers, because calling the function through the wrong type will screw up the whole function calling contract as specified by the ABI. Which could in turn lead to a number of serious bugs like data/stack corruption, runaway code, segfaults etc etc. Solutions like these are the result of a flawed design, so you should take a step back and look for better ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mismatch between the declared function pointer types and the actual functions.

You've declared the function pointer `F` to be of type `double (**F) (double, double)`, which means it should point to a function that takes two `double` parameters and returns a `double`. But your function `F2` is of type `double (*)(double)` as it takes one `double` and returns a `double`. This mismatch might lead to undefined behavior.

If you try to call `(*F)(2,2)`, after `F` was assigned `F2` in the switch case, you are passing an argument to a function (`F2`) that's not expecting it. Even though the function `F2` ignores the second argument, this does not make it correct or safe. It's undefined behavior in C, which means anything can happen. It could work on some platforms and crash on others, or it could cause some other erratic behavior.

To avoid this, you should ensure that the function signature matches with the function pointer. For `f2` and `F2`, the correct function pointer type would be `double (*)(double)`. If you want to use `F` with two doubles, you should ensure that all the functions it might point to accept two doubles.

If you need `F` to be a function that takes two parameters sometimes, and one parameter at other times, you might need to reconsider your design, as this is not directly achievable in C in a safe manner.